# Average number of cars per time unit using HERE traffic API response

Tags: here-api

Is there a way to get the average number of cars per time unit on each road in a bounding-box on a map using HERE traffic API ? or na indicator of this rate ?

The final goal would be to get the info regularly, and give the option to filter and average the data over time to display the results on a map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with any of the APIs currently available on our developer portal. I'm not sure this is available at all, but you can use the contact us form on the portal to enquire about our Enterprise offering around traffic.